# .Net Maui Blazor and Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-webassembly, maui, maui-blazor

can we add blazor web assembly project as a dependency or reference to . Net Maui Blazor project ,this approach worked fine for me on Android And Windows, but the application fails to build with below mentioned error

```
 Portal.Shared is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / browser-wasm.
 Project Portal.Shared supports:
net6.0 android31.0(.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0),
net6.0-ios15.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0),
net6.0-maccatalyst15.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
Restore failed .
```

for the above mentioned issue i have added the following lines

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
```

in the project which i was using as a dependency, but that dint work either . Is Maui still not supported by Mac Vs 2022  ? also can you Kindly make a sample app that works perfectly fine on all platforms which would help us to know MacOs and Ios support to Maui. Kindly help with a workaround.

Comment: Targeting one framework at one time and build that worked for me , works perfectly fine on mac and IOs

Comment: just I wanted to do the same as you. so when I add the  Blazor web assembly project as a dependency or reference, then How I can call it in the Blazor MAUI?

Comment: @Ali You can only  CALL BlazorWasm.Shared folder through MAUI cant reference Client and Server project

Comment: How I can do it?  I have a web blazer assembly project and just I want to have an android version as well.

Comment: If you want a Blazor website(BROWSER) along with android Version of it  Make use of Blazor wasm Client folder And .net Blazor Maui and use a single ASP.net core hosted server Between them and you cant reference Blazor Wasm UI to .net maui blazor @Ali

Comment: do you have a sample project or any document that can help me? like a tutorial for example?  thx

Comment: Im Still working on it @Ali